# Partial view with script tag element violates content security policy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, content-security-policy

Partial view loading using the below ajax code.

```
$.ajax({
          url: '/controller/create',
          dataType: 'html',
          success: function(data) {
             $('#myPartialContainer').html(data);
          }
    });
```

CSP header added

```
default-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; frame-src 'self';
```

_create.cshtml is the partial view from the above ajax request which contain the below script

```
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

How do I add a reference to the script in the partial view (_create.cshtml) without changing the CSP header as mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the header using a meta tag, you should not include script files in the partial view but instead write the whole script inside `<script></script>` tags. I use this technique every time I'm sure the block of code is not going to be used anywhere else.
Otherwise you need a separate file, added to a bundle (maybe) and a meta tag with the CSP header.

Fyi. I’m using $.get() which abstracts some configurations avoiding CSP related errors.

Comment: writing the code inside the <Script></Script> doesn't work because anyhow CSP detects the Script tag in HTML and throws the error.

Comment: In my case it works fine because I'm using $.get() which abstracts some of the configurations away and probably adds some headers for me. You can try this one first. 
I also found an interesting article for bypassing CSP  https://lab.wallarm.com/how-to-trick-csp-in-letting-you-run-whatever-you-want-73cb5ff428aa/

Comment: Yes, correct! We can add script by creating a script element in DOM however we can not trigger the document.ready() of the newly added script after appending the script to DOM. In my case, there are many functions that depend on the document.ready() so it's mandatory to execute.

Comment: I am able to achieve the desired functionality using DOM element creation and calling the method from the document.ready(). I thought it wouldn't be possible.
Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :)